# Is == a shortcut to the Equal() method?

Tags: c#, java, equals

In Java language, I think when you make a comparison like `Object1 == Object2;` by default it compares the Hashcode of the object Except if you rewrite the equal() method because the `==` comparator is a kind of shortcut for the equal method. 
Please correct me if I'm wrong!

The question is, **Is it the same in C#?**

Comment: I *think* it's pretty similar in C#...

Comment: My question is, Is it the same in C#?

Comment: I'm over-ruling the duplicate: that is java; this is c#; different rules (java lacks operators, nullable-t and structs, all of which are involved in this story)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C#, `==` never directly calls `x.Equals(y)` (except perhaps if you include `string.Equals(x,y)`):

- for some inbuilt types, a direct compare is performed (`int`s etc have an opcode)
- if an explicit `==` operator is defined, that is called
- for `Nullable<T>`, "lifted" rules are applied, then `==` is applied to the values if both are non-null
- for classes, the default is reference equality
- for structs, there is no default `==` implementation

Answer (score 3):

By default, the **operator ==** tests for reference equality by determining if two references indicate the same object, so reference types do not need to implement operator == in order to gain this functionality. When a type is immutable, meaning the data contained in the instance cannot be changed, overloading operator == to compare value equality instead of reference equality can be useful because, as immutable objects, they can be considered the same as long as they have the same value. Overriding operator == in non-immutable types is not recommended.

**Equals** is a virtual method, enabling any class to override its implementation. Any class that represents a value, essentially any value type, or a set of values as a group, such as a complex number class, should override Equals. If the type implements IComparable, it should override Equals.

Answer (score 2):

When you compare objects with ==, it compares the references (do they point to the same object). `==` is most definitely not a shortcut for equals.

In C#, == does the same thing with one important difference - in C#, it is possible to overload ==, so it is possible to define new meaning for the operator. For example, string's == compares the contents of the string with another.

Answer (score 1):

In Java as well as in C# the == operator is used to to compare the references while the Equals() methode is comparing the values.

Comment: == doesn`t just check references; it is more complex than that. Use ReferenceEquals for that

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not the same.
obj1 == obj2 is true if both references point to the same object. But for example if those are 2 different string objects that contain the same content, it will be false.

Example:

```
object obj1 = new Something(123);  
object obj2 = new Something(123);

=> obj1 != obj2
```

Comment: That is one string; it is interned

Comment: No, String is the exception that we deal with it as if it is a Value Type so if(str1 == str2) yes it does.

Comment: ups, didn't know that. will adjust the example.